# Do I need a transit visa id buy ticket from partner companies

Tags: transit, transit-visas, self-transfer

As far as I have the experience, if I buy a ticket of ONE airline, no matter how many connecting flights they have in stops of other countries, I don't need a transit visa. Usually, they make us wait in the transit lounges and we are not supposed to get out of the airport. And we don't need the luggage check in and check out again and again.

However, what happens when multiple airlines offer a cheap ticket by partnering together. For example, I found a really nice solution on google flights which combines whizz air and etihad air. However, I don't have (and dont want to apply for) a transit visa of the Golf countries.

My intuition says, as they are partnering, they should do the boarding cards as a single airline do for the connecting flights and also, we should not be needing th transit visa (I am happy to wait in the international transit lounges). However, I am not sure. Any way to confirm it before buying the ticket?

[image]

Comment: What is your nationality?

Comment: If you are self-connecting (do not have a single booking that includes all flights under one Passenger Number Record), airlines only have responsibility for getting you to your interim destination. So they will generally require you to have the visa or documents needed to enter the country where you are self-transfering, even if in theory your itinerary / luggage arrangements means you *don’t* need to enter.

Comment: "if I buy a ticket of ONE airline, I don't need a transit visa". Sorry to say, this is not globally true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tl;dr - You have to self connect.

Long answer

It is not always the case. You have the sole responsibility of ensuring that you have necessary visas, including the transit visas. Airlines will deny you boarding if you do not have a transit visa, even if you are on a single itenary.

One hypothetical example, I am an Indian citizen, traveling from New Delhi (DEL) to London (LHR), via Frankfurt, Germany (FRA). I am using Lufthanza to fly on both legs. I do not plan to get out of airport in Frankfurt. I will be denied boarding since I don't have a transit visa for Germany.

Same in case of flights transiting in US. Every person is required to clear immigration and recheck their bags, even if they are just transiting to a third country.

In your case, there is [no codeshare between Wizz Air and Ethihad](https://simpleflying.com/wizz-air-abu-dhabi-etihad/). You have to self connect in Abu Dhabi. Your citizenship is not mentioned in the question. If you are a Pakistani citizen, you require a visa for UAE. If you are an Italian citizen, you can get on arrival visa, provided you can satisfy the criteria like hotel bookings.

In short, you **will be denied boarding** in Italy, if you do not have a visa for UAE. Also, this itinerary is sold only by kiwi with a self transfer. Its clearly mentioned that self transfer is your responsibility.

[image: Itinerary from FCO to LHE]

Comment: > Airlines will deny you boarding if you do not have a transit visa, even if you are on a single itenary.

This is usually totally false, especially in FRA, airside transit for Indian citizens are definitely possible. For the US though, yes it's right

Comment: @NicolasFormichella Transit in FRA for Indian citizens on the way to UK is *not* possible if the traveller only has a UK visa.  From Timatic *”Nationals of India transiting through Frankfurt (FRA) or Munich (MUC), arriving from a non-Schengen Member State with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight within 24 hours to a third country which is not a Schengen Member State. They must:
- have a visa issued by Bulgaria, Canada, Cyprus, Ireland (Rep.), Japan, Romania or USA, and
- stay in the international transit area of the airport, and
- have documents required for their next destination.”*

Comment: You're right, didn't know A-visa requirements were reintroduced

Comment: @NicolasFormichella I checked TIMATIC before mentioning that scenario. :)